# C# with SQLite and foreign key

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to implement a patients data base for our software, and have an issue with the foreign key statement. I am using the latest SQLite DLLs, with C#.

When I try to run below code:

```
dbConnection = "Data Source=SQLiteMyDatabase.db;foreign keys=true;";
if (connections == 0)
{
  cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
  cnn.Open();
  this.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patients ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;");
  this.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images ( FOREIGN KEY (patientID) REFERENCES patients(id), nameRed VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;");
}
```

I get the error:

```
SQLite error near "FOREIGN": syntax error
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: are you sure this.ExecuteNonQuery is not wrong statement?

Comment: What do you mean? The first data table works fine, and something in my second query must be wrong. I already tested the first table, and it works fine, the second causes the error. So yes, the statement is wrong, but I do not know yet where.

Comment: this should be cnn.ExecuteNonQuery...

Comment: the cnn is a private static object to the class, and will use the ExecuteNonQuery on cnn, that itself works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create a foreign key, you must first create the column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (
    nameRed VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    patientID INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (patientID) REFERENCES patients(id) 
 );
```

Please note:

1. I moved the primary key column (`nameRed`) first in the list of columns created, but that's just convention.  It could go second.
2. You use the data type VARCHAR and SQlite will accept that, but be aware that it gets mapped to type TEXT, the maximum length will be ignored, and you will be able to store other data types in the column.  SQLite is a bit funny when it comes to data types (it has a very well thought-out system but it's quite different from most other SQL databases).
3. To make things more confusing, you *are* allowed to declare the PRIMARY KEY as a property of the column (although you can also do it after the list of columns as with the FOREIGN KEY).

Comment: Ah nice, thanks, it now works. I am not that familiar with data bases, and could not see whats wrong there.

Comment: What do you mean with the 2nd comment? "You will be able to store other data types in the column"?

Comment: SQLite uses dynamic typing; it allows you to insert *anything* in your column. See [Datatypes In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Ah, nice, never knew that. Thanks a lot.